# Appsync Javascript client choice

Tags: aws-appsync

I would like to use straight forward vanilla JavaScript to create an AppSync web client front end. All the examples seem to demonstrate using React. Do you have to use a JavaScript framework? Any pointers to a good resouce would be welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend checking out Amplify - https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js

But if you wish to wish remain as "vanilla" as possible then you will have to use the AWS JS SDK. https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js

Comment: Thank you Ashwin, this is certainly a great help